# Make background transparent on personalized component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hy, I am creating my own component for showing percentage, when I draw it in the OnPaint() override, I create a drawArea and a drawBuffer to make the drawing procedures, the problem is that this area has a background color and I want to make it transparent. See image bellow.
[image]

Here in this image, the component is on top of the Form1 and I cant see through the loading component. How can I set it in a way I can see through?

Comment: Uh, I can't really tell what's going on by looking at the picture. I assume that big elliptical thing with the gray background is the thing you want to make transparent? Is it a Panel control? A PictureBox control? A UserControl? And what's the form's background? A spinning pinwheel repeated over and over again? Is that the form's BackgroundImage? Have you set the big-elliptical-thing-control's BackgroundColor to Transparent?

Comment: I already solved it, it was some of those details I didn't pay attention, I just needed to set the Component's class background to Color.Transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening, the Component I created was in a different class, I had to set the BackColor = Color.Transparent inside the components class.
Simple like that.